# printing '\u0000' in Java

Tags: java, unicode, char

When I run

```
char c= '\u0000'; 
System.out.println(c);
```

in Eclipse,it prints a little square which means a null character.
But it prints 'a' when I run it in CLI.
Then I run it on other computers, some print 'a', some print a space.

Why would this happen?

My OS is Windows 7 professional-32bit.The other systems are windows xp.
My java version is jdk_1.6.0update12.

Comment: What's the character encoding of your command prompt?

Comment: windows console does not handle unicode correctly.  Redirect it to a file, it show the correct output.

Comment: If you use a sane font (i.e. not raster fonts) the Windows console should show Unicode correctly, barring complex scripts. It supports Unicode if you feed it Unicode and with raster fonts there's a display conversion to the OEM codepage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not print a for me:

```
public class Mkt {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    char c= '\u0000'; 
    System.out.println("-" + c + "-");
  }
}

$ javac Mkt.java && java Mkt
--
```

Ubuntu 11.10 here:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_26"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Things to check / try:

- Change the font of your terminal window
- Did you try with other Java versions on your machine?
- Is there something different between your machine and others you tried?
- Try it from within [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
- Try some different console emulator, e.g. [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)
- Redirect to file (`java Mkt > some_file.txt`) and see what's in it, preferably with some hex editor
- Make a small Swing application and display that in [JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html) to see if it displays the same
- What does `\u0001` display?

Comment: (a) Console windows are not terminal windows. (b) There are no console emulators, except things like zsnes, etc. – you might be looking for the term »terminal emulator« and even that'd be wrong on Windows – Console just polls a hidden console window for changes and copies the screen buffer; hardly magic and hardly emulating anything. (c) Redirecting to a file inherits the same idiosyncrasies of the Windows console, by the way.

Comment: I hava checked ,when I change the font ,It shows a space. redireted to a file, it shows a little square.So I think the reason is windows console does not handle unicode correctly